# Access is denied error in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting 'Access is denied' error with IE11 with my Angular project. This works fine in Chrome. I am not able to figure what is going wrong with IE as I am
relatively new to web development with javascript and Angular.

Can someone help me with what is going wrong with IE11 for the below code please?

```
this.http.get(url)
    .subscribe(
        res => {
            if (typeof(logInfo.callBack) === 'function') {
                logInfo.callBack(res);
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question with the information given. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with the code snippet you posted. How are you accessing your website? Is it served from a local webserver or a remote one? What exactly does the error stacktrace look like?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a CORS related issue.

The IE browser is using *XDomainRequest* which involves some limitations. One of them is: the protocol must be preserved (requests are allowed from HTTP to HTTP, from HTTPS to HTTPS. Other protocols are prohibited).

So, if you app is loaded over 'https' but is trying to load the resource over "http" or vice versa, than the request will be blocked by IE browser.

Comment: This was exactly the problem for me. I wish this was higher up. I have searched high and low.